# Dual Listbox select item to remove

Tags: c#, listbox, items

So I have two list boxes and I want to click on an listbox item and I want the other listbox to correspond and select the same row as well.  That way I would select two items in two listbox on the same row with one click.  How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Set the SelectedIndex property of the second text box to correspond with the item you want to select.

Comment: can you give me an example?